# ObjectStateManager error on attach in foreach loop entity frameworks

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have a table of (new) users and a table of groups. What I'm trying to do is add the users to the groups.

What I thought I'd do is  :-

```
using(context = new MyEntity())
{
    foreach(csvUser from csvSource)
    {
        User oUser = new User();
        oUser.Firstname = csvUser.Firstname;

        Group oGroup = new Group();
        // Set the primary key for attach
        oGroup.ID = csvUser.GroupID;
        context.Group.Attach(oGroup);

        oUser.Groups.Add(oGroup);
        context.Users.Add(oUser);
    }   

    context.saveChnages();
}
```

So bascially loop through all the new users, grab their group id from the CSV File (group already exists in db). So I would attach to the group and then add the group.

However I'm running into an error because as soon as a user with group id which has already been attached tries to attach it booms.

> An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could
>   not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of
>   the supplied object match the key values of the object to which
>   changes must be applied.

Which I can understand, its trying to re-attach an object its already attached to in memory. However is there a way around this? All I need to do is attach a new user to a pre-existing group from the database.

Comment: Why are you trying to `attach` it anyway? by 'adding' you're already 'attaching' the entity and changing it's state to 'added'.

Comment: Also, you're creating a 'group' for each 'user' which is (as far as i understand) not what you want. you better add your 'groups' first, then add the users with 'user.Group = group'.

Comment: haim770 - the groups already exist, I'm just trying to associate them. Only the users are new.

Answer (score 1):

That error is usually associated with the `ApplyCurrentValues` in some form or shape - when it tries to update your (previously) detached entity.

It's not entirely clear why is that happening in your case - but maybe you have something else going on - or you're just 'confusing' EF with having attaching the same group over again.

The simplest way I think is to just use `Find` - and avoid `Attach`

```
context.Group.Find(csvUser.GroupID);
```

Which loads from cache if there is one - or from Db if needed.

> If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context,
>   then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store.
>   Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given
>   primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the
>   context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the
>   store, then null is returned

That should fix things for you.

You could also turn off applying values form Db I think (but I'm unable to check that at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a many-to-many relationship between Users and Groups. If that is the case and you are using Code-First then you model could be defined like this...

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    // Other User properties...
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other Group properties...
    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Next, configure the many-to-many relationship...

```
public class UserGroupsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserGroup>
{
    public UserGroupsConfiguration()
    {
        // Define a composite key
        HasKey(a => new { a.UserId, a.GroupId });

        // User has many Groups
        HasRequired(a => a.User)
            .WithMany(s => s.UserGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        // Group has many Users
        HasRequired(a => a.Group)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.GroupId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Add the configuration in your DbContext class...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserGroupsConfiguration());
    ...
}
```

Now your task is simpler...

```
foreach (var csvUser in csvSource)
{
    User oUser = new User();
    oUser.Firstname = csvUser.Firstname;

    // Find Group
    var group = context.Groups.Find(csvUser.GroupID);

    if(group == null)
    {
       // TODO: Handle case that group is null
    }
    else
    {
        // Group found, assign it to the new user
        oUser.UserGroups.Add(new UserGroup { Group = group });
        context.Users.Add(oUser);
    }
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you're adding a new `Group` for each `User` you're iterating on, try this:

```
using(context = new MyEntity())
{
    // fetch Groups and add them first
    foreach(groupId in csvSource.Select(x => x.GroupID).Distinct())
    {
         context.Groups.Add(new Group { ID = groupId });
    }

    // add users
    foreach(csvUser from csvSource)
    {
        User oUser = new User();
        oUser.Firstname = csvUser.Firstname;

        var existingGroup = context.Groups.Single(x => x.Id == csvUser.GroupID);
        oUser.Groups.Add(existingGroup);

        context.Users.Add(oUser);
    }   

    context.saveChnages();
}
```